# Webpack Dev Server Proxy Is Ignored

Tags: javascript, proxy, webpack-dev-server

I have webpack dev server running on `http://localhost:8080` and an express server running on `https://localhost:443`. I'm proxying to `:443` in my webpack dev server config. My express server works fine with Postman but when I make a `fetch` request from `:8080`, I get `400 (Bad Request)`. When I print the response, `response.url` is still `http://localhost:8080`.

I've been through several other posts and have tried the following config:

- `secure: false` (The certificates I'm using are invalid)
- `changeOrigin: true`
- `router: () => 'https://localhost:443'`
- fetch request URL set to `https://localhost:443`

When running webpack dev server, I see `Proxy created: /api  -> https://localhost:443` in the terminal. What am I missing?

My webpack dev server config looks like this:

```
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'https://localhost:443',
                secure: false,
                changeOrigin: true
            },
            logLevel: 'debug'
        }
    }
```

My fetch request looks like this:

```
        var response = await fetch('/api/create_link_token', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: { idToken },
                url: 'https://localhost:443'
            }),
            data = await response;
            console.log(response); // response.url is http://localhost:8080/api/create_link_token
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some issues:

1. No `url` option exists for the [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) function.
2. The HTTP request URL should be `http://localhost:8081/api/create_link_token`, in this way, the HTTP proxy middleware will proxy the `/api` to `https://localhost:8443`.
3. The `body` accepts a JSON string, like `JSON.stringify({ idToken: 1 })`.

Below is a working example:

`client/src/index.js`:

```js
function main() {
    fetch('/api/create_link_token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ idToken: 1 }),
    })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => console.log('data: ', data));
}

main();
```

`client/webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        clean: true,
    },
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'https://localhost:8443',
                secure: false,
                changeOrigin: true,
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.html'),
        }),
    ],
};
```

`server/app.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/api/create_link_token', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200).json({ code: 0 });
});

app.get('/ok', (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

const serverOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './ssl/key.pem')),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './ssl/cert.pem')),
};

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const httpsServer = https.createServer(serverOptions, app);

httpServer.listen(8080);
httpsServer.listen(8443);
```

Start the webpack dev server by running `webpack serve`, logs:

```bash
> webpack serve

<i> [webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Proxy created: /api  -> https://localhost:8443
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:8081/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] On Your Network (IPv4): http://192.168.10.197:8081/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from 'D:\workspace\mrdulin\webpack-samples\webpack-v5\stackoverflow\77877176\client\public' directory
asset main.js 265 KiB [emitted] (name: main)
asset index.html 297 bytes [emitted]
runtime modules 27.2 KiB 12 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/ 177 KiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/ 71.8 KiB 16 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/webpack/hot/*.js 5.18 KiB
    ./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js 1.94 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/webpack/hot/log.js 1.74 KiB [built] [code generated]
    + 2 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/*.js 81.8 KiB
    ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/index.js 7.91 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/named-references.js 73 KiB [built] [code generated]   
    ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/numeric-unicode-map.js 339 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/surrogate-pairs.js 537 bytes [built] [code generated] 
  ./node_modules/ansi-html-community/index.js 4.16 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/events/events.js 14.5 KiB [built] [code generated]
./src/index.js 254 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.90.1 compiled successfully in 533 ms
```

Refresh the HTML page multiple times, the logs of the server:

```bash
{ idToken: 1 }
{ idToken: 1 }
{ idToken: 1 }
```

The logs in the browser console:

[image]

Comment: the main problem was the JSON.stringify. works without the rest. thanks Lin!